# Django Extend admin index

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I wish to make some modifications to the Django admin interface (specifically, remove the "change" link, while leaving the Model name as a link to the page for changes to the instances). I can achieve this by copying and pasting index.html from the admin application, and making the modifications to the template, but I would prefer to only override the offending section by extending the template - however I am unsure how to achieve this as the templates have the same name. I am also open to alternative methods of achieving this effect. (django 1.7, python 3.4.1)

Comment: If you don't want the "change" link displayed, this is probably better done via overriding the `has_change_permission()` on the associated AdminModel.(I realize this is old be for people coming to it now)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Worked it out - I set `admin.site.index_template = "my_index.html"` in admin.py, and then the my_index template can inherit from admin/index.html without a name clash.

Comment: Awesome! Fantastic! Simple! I did the same thing but in projects urls.py.

Comment: This should go into the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class) since it's so simple

Answer (score 3):

Might be cleaner to override the index_template for AdminSite:

```py
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
AdminSite.index_template = '...'
```

Though again, that might be made more external-code-friendly by either: changing this on a custom instance before binding, or subclassing a custom AdminSite and overriding there, and registering that custom AdminSite instead.

Relevant documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#root-and-login-templates

Edit: To clarify - this would allow you to just override the section you're changing in the template, and so inherit any upstream changes.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer for overriding standard admin templates (not linked to a specific model)

You need to have the app in which you are overriding the template set *BEFORE*, `'django.contrib.admin'` in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39964906/24718

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove change permissions for a model, you can do this programmatically in your admin class for the model rather than modifying the templates. This gives you the advantage of being able to enable/disable the link based on user criteria. Changing the permission will be reflected at the Change List, Change Form and in the admin index.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from your_app.models import YourModel

class CustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, obj=None):
        # check request.user creds, etc
        return False

admin.site.register(YourModel, CustomModelAdmin)
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission for more information about Django admin options

Comment: This is not what I wish to achieve. Change permissions should still be available, as clicking the Model name on the admin index links to the same page as the "change" button. I only wish to remove the change button, not the ability to make the changes via the other link

Comment: Ok, then you're better off just tweaking the template code.

Answer (score -1):

In case you want to append new stuff to right sidebar, I'd suggest to use jQuery

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block sidebar %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <div id="extra_sidebar">
    <div class="module">
      <h2>Custom functions</h2>
      <a style="padding-left: 15px" href="/admin/extra/">My extra link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#content-related').prepend($('#extra_sidebar').contents());
      });
    })(django.jQuery);
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```