# Django admin template override not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Django 1.6.11

App structure looks like:

```
my_project/
     |-- new_app/
     |-- templates/
```

in my config:

```
TEMPLATE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_ROOT, 'templates/')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_ROOT,
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'new_app',
)
```

I've also tried listing `new_app` before `contrib.admin` and that didn't help.

When I copy `venv/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html` to my `/templates/admin/new_app/change_list.html` I don't see my customizations show up.

```
my_project/
     |-- new_app/
     |-- templates/
         |-- admin/
             |-- new_app/
                 |-- change_list.html
```

When I move change_list.html up one level so it's under the admin path, the changes show up just fine:

```
my_project/
     |-- new_app/
     |-- templates/
         |-- admin/
             |-- change_list.html
             |-- new_app/   (now an empty folder)
```

... but of course that would mean my changes are going to affect every admin page, not just for the app I'm trying to modify.

I've added this to the app's only model within admin.py:

```
class MyModelAdmin(reversion.VersionAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/new_app/change_list.html'
```

... this gives me some of what I need, but I also need change_list_results.html and there's no ModelAdmin override for that.

I'm following the documentation guide found at [readthedocs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django/1.6.x/django.pdf) in section 2.4.8 on page 31, but I don't seem to be having any luck.

Comment: I know this is a very old question. But I am having almost the exact same issue on Django 2.1.1. Did you ever resolve this as none of the below solutions work for me. 


I'm also trying to do this for a specific model, which is located in a separate project.  My folder structure looking similar:
my_project/
     |-- api/
     |-- frontend/
     |-- templates/
         |-- admin/
             |-- api/
                 |-- specificmodel/
                       |-- change_list.html

Comment: Well I figured out why it wasn't working... and probably why this wasn't working. You are extending reversion.VersionAdmin and that is probably overriding your template changes. 

For me it was because I was extending ImportExportModelAdmin.

That being said I'm still not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 21):

When several applications provide different versions of the same resource (template, static file, management command, translation), the application listed first in INSTALLED_APPS has precedence. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS).

Change:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'new_app',
)
```

To:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'new_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
)
```

Your templates in `new_app` should now be found before the templates in `contrib.admin`.

Comment: I've tried this too, didn't help. Wrote an edit into my question stating so. Thanks, though!!

Comment: Did you restart? The dev server auto restart isn't enough.

Comment: Does your TEMPLATE settings have `loaders` defined? I guess the default should be okay (no loaders defined). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader

Comment: Would loaders be in my config file only? My config only has a few matches for `template` in a search, where we explicitly set for `TEMPLATE_ROOT`, `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` where we added custom code for third-party SSO.

Comment: TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS are irrelevant, they only do stuff in the request response cycle. TEMPLATE_ROOT and _DIRS can have influence if these locations contain a `change_list.html`. Modify the django.contrib.admin `change_list.html` (path/to/site-pagages/django/contrib/admin/templates) temporary to see if that is the template used.

Comment: And yes, loaders are defined in `settings.py` and if not, the default is used. To make sure do: `python manage.py shell --settings=somesettings` and then `form django.conf import settings; print settings.TEMPLATES`. TEMPLATES is a list with dicts.

Comment: Thanks so much for your ideas, by the way! As mentioned in my post, if I move the change_list.html and change_list_results.html from `/templates/admin/new_app/` up one level to `/templates/admin/` it works just fine (but then affects everything). And yes, I've triple checked the spelling of my app name and corresponding /templates/admin/*/ path for the app. :)

Comment: In the development shell you can also do something like: `from django.template.loader import get_template` and `get_template('admin/change_list.html').backend.template_dirs` to inspect the paths that are used to lookup this template. There must be  some other app that takes precedence.

Comment: I've tried variations of that for the past hour and can't figure out how to get the path of the template. I'll keep at it, though.

Comment: It might be Django 1.6 as I tested this on 1.10. Last tip, install (a old version of) django-debug toolbar. It displays the template path as well.

Comment: it did not work for me

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using a templates folder inside your app? Something like this:

```
my_project/
     |-- new_app/
         |-- templates/
             |-- new_app/
                 |-- admin/
                     |-- change_list.html
     |-- templates/
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the answer. All of the tutorials I saw said the hierarchy of the templates had to be something like `project > templates > admin > app > change_list.html` which didn't work. I ended up taking a different approach, but I'm still curious how to get this other way working, so I'll try this out a little later.

Comment: In my project I do it the way I suggested and it works well. It's worth a try.

Comment: It did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I came here because I was having a very similar problem.  James Parker got me on the right track by looking at extended versions of ModelAdmin.  I had a Mixin and an overloaded Admin like so:
`class EvaluationAdmin(ExportMixin, MarkdownxModelAdmin):`.  It turned out the ExportMixin was hardcoding the template preventing the normal template override from working.  I did not find a solution mentioned anywhere and this might not be the most elegant but I fixed it by subclassing ExportMixin and hardcoding the template to my overridden one instead.  Just be sure to start with the copy the mixin was using to keep any additional features it was providing ('admin/import_export/change_list_export.html' in this case).

```
class EvaluationExportMixin(ExportMixin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/eval/evaluation/change_list_export.html'

class EvaluationAdmin(EvaluationExportMixin, MarkdownxModelAdmin):
    ...
```

Hopefully this might point someone else to where to look and one possible work-around.

Answer (score -1):

Go to page 607.

> **Custom template options**  The *Overriding admin templates* section describes how to override or extend the default
>   admin templates. Use the following options to override the default templates used by the `ModelAdmin` views:

And there you will got options how to override templates for specific models with `ModelAdmin`.

The same(i didn't compare, but seems similar) docs can be found on django site: [*Custom template options*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options)

Comment: If I add `change_list_template = 'admin/new_app/change_list.html` I see some the changes from that file, but I also need change_list_results.html and there's no ModelAdmin modifier for that that I can readily see. Also, isn't `change_list.html` supposed to work just by having the template file in the /templates/admin/new_app/ path?

Comment: @iandouglas jeez, you're right, it should work, don't know whats the problem... If i came up with smth, i'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate anything else you can think of to try.