# How to redirect is_staff user to custom template in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I have a simple issue: I tried to redirect the login page to another page depending on the user role (staff/normal). Normal users have their own dashboard and staff users have the overall dashboard.

The redirect function for normal users work perfectly fine. However, for the staff users, it keeps redirecting me to the django-admin page instead of my custom template.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748396/django-extend-admin-index) but it is not working.

[image: Staff Redirected Page]

*views.py*

```
#login
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return redirect('staff_dashboard')
        else:
            return redirect('user_dashboard')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST.get("username")
            password = request.POST.get("password")

            user = auth.authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_staff:
                    auth.login(request,user)
                    return redirect('staff_dashboard')
                else:
                    auth.login(request,user)
                    return redirect('user_dashboard')
            else:
                messages.info(request,"Username or Password is incorrect")
                return redirect('login')


#staff_dashboard
@login_required(login_url='login')
def staff_dashboard(request):
    vid_size = []
    img_query_set = model_images.objects.all()
    img_query_set_count = model_images.objects.all().count()
    vid_query_set = model_videos.objects.all()
    vid_query_set_count = model_videos.objects.all().count()
    
    for item in vid_query_set:
        size = round(item.vid_path.size / 1000000,1)
        vid_size.append(size)
    
    context = {
        "img_query_set": img_query_set,
        "vid_query_set": vid_query_set,
        "img_query_set_count": img_query_set_count,
        "vid_query_set_count": vid_query_set_count,
    }
    return render(request,'admin/index.html',context)
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('user/dashboard', views.user_dashboard, name='user_dashboard'),
    path('staff/dashboard', views.staff_dashboard, name='staff_dashboard'),
]
```

Comment: Have you tried to do this with your own template? You appear to be using the django admin template so that may be part of your problem.

Comment: it does redirect you correctly, and correctly renders admin/index.html template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it. You can't make a file with the name 'admin' inside the templates folder. It will conflict with the Django-admin templates. I rename the file and its working now.